# How to address multicollinearity in multinomial regression without dropping independent variables?

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, multinomial-distribution, multicollinearity

In my statistical model, using multinomial logistic regression, I have used **age**, **region** (urban/ rural) and **number of pregnancies (G)** as independent variables. As expected, **Age** and **G** are correlated (rho=0.5, p<0.000) and there is a weak correlation between **G** and **region**. Highest level of pseudo-R squared value is achieved when I include **G** and **region**, but I cannot (At least I think so) drop age as it is an important predictor variable.

1. Is there some kind of mediator effect ? and can I address it in multinomial regression?
2. Is there anyway to include both of the variables? or perhaps using a merged variable, such as (age*g)?

And, these are a bit irrelevant but anyway...

3. Should I drop insignificant variables that contribute strongly to overall pseudo R squared?

4.What does this warning mean and how to address it ? **"Unexpected singularities in the Hessian matrix are encountered. This indicates that either some predictor variables should be excluded or some categories should be merged."**

Thank you for your response, forgive me for any possible statistical mistakes, as I'm quite new to this!

---

After JKP and AaronDefazio's comments,

Here is the code spss produced: (included pregNum, Age and region not included)

NOMREG CTstat (BASE=FIRST ORDER=ASCENDING) BY PregNum NEW_PT TStat35 UStat WITH GDPGr EduLvl

/CRITERIA CIN(95) DELTA(0) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(5) CHKSEP(20) LCONVERGE(0) PCONVERGE(0.000001) SINGULAR(0.00000001)

/MODEL
  /STEPWISE=PIN(.05) POUT(0.1) MINEFFECT(0) RULE(SINGLE) ENTRYMETHOD(LR) REMOVALMETHOD(LR)

/INTERCEPT=INCLUDE

/PRINT=FIT PARAMETER SUMMARY LRT CPS STEP MFI.

---

And here is the frequency tables for my categorical variables included in the regression.

[image: Frequency table]

Comment: It would help greatly if you post your dataset and the code you have used so far.

Comment: @AaronDefazio, thanks for your response. I mostly used SPSS predefined commands ( point & click ! ), only multinomial regression in the regression menu to be precise, so no coding. Unfortunately, I cannot post the dataset online, as I do not have the rights to do so & will be fired in all probabilities!

Comment: Still, pasting the syntax from the dialog box and posting it would help.  Also, if you can, post the output you are getting or at least frequency tables for your categorical variables.

Comment: CTStat has categories with too few cases to facilitate this analysis.  You'll want to collapse into fewer categories to solve the singularity problem.  Also note that your GUI selection provides for stepwise variable selection;  this has drawbacks for your situation, and you can read about this on this site.  But in that respect and others you ask important questions that get into topics too lengthy for an answer on a single page; sustained study is called for.  Good luck ~

Comment: Thanks again! I'd very much appreciate a link to a source of study. unfortunately I wasn't able to find the answers to my questions.